# Developing apps for Windows 8 pro

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am developing an application for Windows RT using C# for Tablets. Due to insufficient APIs for device management(device screen lock, n/w config, restrict camera, etc.,.) our client has decided to shift to Windows 8 pro. Well do we have any template for developing tablet apps for Windows 8 pro(I am using C# with XAML in "Windows Store Apps" templates for win rt), or how to create tablet apps for Windows 8 pro.

Answer (score 1):

A windows store app stays a windows store app - either way, you develop it for RT/PRO or desktop. You can use a windows 8 desktop app and run it on a PRO machine. You can even sell your desktop app through the store!

Answer (score 0):

If your client has decided to shift to Windows 8 Pro, you should be able to use project templates in Visual Studio to develop Windows 8 apps unless I am missing something here.

If you have to develop apps for Windows on ARM, you may want to check out Jason Zander’s blog on 
"What you need to know about developing for Windows on ARM (WOA)" at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/06/12/what-you-need-to-know-about-developing-for-windows-on-arm-woa.aspx

Comment: Dear Zhiming Xue thanks for your reply.In vs2012 we have a collection templates for windows store apps.But I need a template for windows 8 pro apps development for tablet.-Sathia